# Paginación con SqlAlchemy Flask, Marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, paginación, sqlalchemy

Estoy desarrollando en `Flask` una `API` con `SqlAlchemy` y `Marshmallow`. La idea es poder recibir como parametro en la ruta el numero de pagina para realizar una paginacion. Y devolver un JSON

```
@users.route('/page/<int:page>', methods=['GET'])
def paginationUsers(page):
    page = page
    per_page = 10
    result = User.query.paginate(page, per_page=per_page)
    return jsonify(result),200
```

Entiendo que result es un `Objeto Pagination` y no puede ser serializado. Como podria hacerlo?